# MS Bot Framework (NodeJs) mocha testing without duplicate logic

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, botframework, bots

I am considering using MS Bot Framework, mainly for the ability to write unit tests, instead of testing through the messenger. I did some digging around and found several questions about testing that lead to examples of tests.

The issue was that the tests contained the actual bot logic, which is kinda dumb considering that in tests you normally only write the requests and check the responses/results to be equal to something. So is there a way to handle tests with just starting the bot locally and not copying its logic to the tests?

Answer (score 0):

It's *theoretically possible*, but *highly impractical.*

It would involve copying a large part of the BotBuilder Emulator code (itself requiring a substantial amount of time to go through and understand), and running that within the test environment.  Also, I have found that when I attempted this with the actual emulator, the tests failed with the responses from the bot going to the emulator and not to the test as expected.

The more practical solution is to use an NPM package [bot-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bot-tester) that can simplify the test, or using the general methodology of including the bot logic in the tests themselves as is the norm.  Either way, some bot logic would have to be included in your tests.